# Is there an Android app that allows me to record only the callers voice and not mine?

Tags: android, audio

When interviewing people in a podcast it would be wonderful to record only the callers voice and not us in the studio. We have professional microphones and would like to merge the output from them with the callers voice (calling to an android phone). Is there an app that only records the incoming sound (or record both but in separate files) or is it impossible to separate them due to restrictions in the operating system?

The price of the app is of lesser importance, but a free one is better of course.

All in all I'm looking for an app that

- Runs on Android
- Records incoming sound during call only or separates incoming/outgoing into separate audio files.
- If possible records the audio as a raw format like wav

Comment: That would most likely be one of the [call recording apps](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists.php?topic=cat;id=23#group_98). Though I didn't encounter one matching your requirements, hopefully someone else has.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest rather than an Android application trying to use a Bluetooth or wired connection to the phone from a PC and using the PC/Mac as the Microphone & Headset for the phone.  Depending on the OS you should then be able to record the incoming and outgoing audio to separate tracks at a good quality level.  There are a number of sound recording applications for each OS but some sound cards have the recording of outgoing audio disabled see [here](http://manual.audacityteam.org/o/man/tutorial_recording_computer_playback_on_windows.html) for some more information.

Answer (score 2):

[Call Recorder](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=polis.app.callrecorder) would make the job.

You can set the 'File format' or 'Audio channel' [Settings](https://bitly.com/1pilk39).
Call recorder has an option to record only the callers voice. You can go to settings Audio Source and select: Phone line, Mic, Own voice or Opponent voice.

But, it's possible that your device isn't supported (see the list in the Google play store main site).